# Can someone tell me the difference between the call in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a method called Display. Can somebody explain me the difference of calling the same method in the following two ways.

1. `[self Display];`
2. `[self performselector:@selector(Display)]`

`- (void)Display {
     NSlog(@"Data");
}`

Answer (score 2):

both are basically the same with one minute difference.. @selector gives a name to your method which you can pass around as an attribute to other objects or in other function calls.
Like if you want to send a message to other object and you want to send display as an attribute then you will have to give it a name using @selector and thus you can send it.. its a pretty vague concept.. hope this helps.

and to quote apple documents...

> "However, the performSelector: method allows you to send messages that
>   aren’t determined until runtime. A variable selector can be passed as
>   the argument:
>
> SEL myMethod = findTheAppropriateSelectorForTheCurrentSituation();
>
> [anObject performSelector:myMethod];
>
> The aSelector argument should identify a method that takes no
>   arguments. For methods that return anything other than an object, use
>   NSInvocation."

Answer (score 1):

1. `[self Display]` is shorter and easier to read, write and comprehend.
2. `[self performSelector:@selector(Display)]` makes it possible to execute arbitrary selectors. If you save the selector in a variable, then you can execute it later on without knowing the method you invoke. It is therefore more flexible. Even better: you can pass selectors and objects to other objects and let them invoke it for you when necessary. An example why you want to use this is the [NSUndoManager](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUndoManagerTutorial) which simple invokes a selector to undo an action if the user executes the Undo command.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a big difference between examples you provided, but perform selector is very useful when you for instance wanna move execution of your method to the background thread.

Comment: dont you have performselectorinbackground for that...?

Answer (score 0):

`[self Display];` **is a call to a known method on a known object.**
It's easy to give it some params if your want : `[self DisplayWithParam1:(NSString*)aString param2:(int)aNumber param3:(NSDictionary*)aDict`

`[self performselector:@selector(Display)]` **is a call** that allows you to call a **possibly not known method on a possibly not known object** type.

Let's imagine you have many kind of classes that all respond to a given protocol that require to have the `Display` method implemented. You put some objects of thoses different classes in an NSMutableArray. When parsing the array later, you will get `id` typed objects.

So calling`[myArrayObject Display];` will work at runtime but will generate a warning at compile time as `id` does not support any method of course, even if you know that this object supports the method.
To prevent thoses warning, call `[myArrayObject performselector:@selector(Display)];`.
The problem with that call is that is **harder to pass some parameters**.

Answer (score 0):

```
    performSelector:withObject:withObject:

Sends a message to the receiver with two objects as arguments. 
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject withObject:(id)anotherObject
Parameters

aSelector

    A selector identifying the message to send. If aSelector is NULL, an NSInvalidArgumentException is raised.
anObject

    An object that is the first argument of the message.
anotherObject

    An object that is the second argument of the message

Return Value

An object that is the result of the message.
Discussion

This method is the same as performSelector: except that you can supply two arguments for aSelector. aSelector should identify a method that can take two arguments of type id. For methods with other argument types and return values, use NSInvocation.
Availability

    Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html

Answer (score -2):

The @select call is faster. Generally the uglier (and less dynamic) the code you have in Objective-C, the faster it runs. Here, [the selector call bypasses the usual call](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/artikel/Optimization/opti-3.html) to `objc_msgSend()`.

I wouldn't recommend writing code like this if you can avoid it. Selectors are somewhat common in Cocoa, but if you're using it for a speedup it's really not worth it. `objc_msgSend()` is highly optimized and very fast.

Comment: This is incorrect.  `-performSelector:` is itself an Objective-C method and it incurs all of the same overhead that sending the message directly incurs.  Then it has to do all the same stuff again to get the implementation for the selector.  So the second option incurs aboutr twice the overhead of the first option.

Comment: Ahh disregard my post then. Sorry about the confusion.